# Real Time Phone Call Translator App in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, flutter-dependencies, translate, phone-call

How can we make an app that can Translate Phone Calls in Real-Time? Like speeches are translated at the UN.
Is there any package or procedure in Flutter with which we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your end goal, There are several components needed to achieve it. You need the following:

-Speech-To-Text for language conversion to text and you can achieve this in Flutter by using a speech recognition plugin.

-Google Cloud Translation API for the basic language text translation.

-Text-To-Speech to translate back the text to the spoken language.

-Communication Infra to establish a real-time communication channel.

This is just a high level analysis of the possible path of your use case,attached are documentation for your additional reference.[1][2][3][4]

[1] https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition

[2] https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

[3] https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs

[4] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API